# How to Update/delete children with compound key in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I having a little confusing trying to understand how children entities work into Jpa. Here is what I have:

I've created this classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name="savedreport")
public class Report {
  @Id
  private int id;
  private String reportName;
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn (name ="savedReportId", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private Collection<ReportColumn> columns;
  private String owner;
  // getters&setters...
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "savedcolumn")
@IdClass(value = ColumnId.class)
public class ReportColumn {
  @Id
  private String savedReportId;
  @Id
  private String columnName;
  private int columnOrder;
  // more getters&setters
}
```

*ColumnId* goes like this:

```
public class ColumnId implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private String columnName;
  private String savedReportId;
  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
     return reporteId.hashCode() + field.hashCode();
  }
}
```

Lastly, I declared a jpa repository

```
public interface ReportRepository extends JpaRepository<Report, String> {

Collection<Report> findByOwnerUserName (String userName);

}
```

With this setup I was capable to insert and select data from my database without any problem, through the...

```
reportRepository.save();
```

... method from jpaRepository. My problem begins when a try to save a Report with less columns than the already saved on database. When I set show_sql = true to see what's going on I notice hibernate query is pretending to update a non-included column like this:

```
update savedcolumn set savedReportId = null where savedReportId = ?
```

What I think is happening is that hiberate tries to detach Report entity from Column by updating to null the "join" column in table. If this is the case, I'd like to ask you first: if I'm doing a correct ORM mapping for my entities. And, second, how can I setup this entities in order to tell hibernate that I want the Report children to be deleted, rather than "detached" when I save less columns.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'va also tried to use orphanRemoval like this:

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn (name ="savedReport", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Collection<ReportColumn> columns;

But it doesn't seems to make any difference.

Comment: I think your mapping is wrong, please check this article http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id

Comment: Anyway there are two ways of implementing composite keys 1- http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/01/jpa-idclass-example/ 2- http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/01/jpa-embeddedid-example/ but i always do prefer second way which uses [at]Embeddable and [at]EmbeddedId